# Flash animation-like 2d graphical library for C++ or Java

Tags: java, c++, user-interface

I'm looking for a good (hopefully free) 2d graphical library in C++, or in worst case, Java, which helps create the look and feel of Flash animations, the typical ones you can find in most flash games.

The best would be if it provided most of the features and easiness of Flash animation programming, like layers, or even collision detection, etc., without all the micromanagement of pixels typical for opengl. Of course, it can be built upon opengl...

Edit: interactivity is important, it might not been clear in the first description. So I'm not aiming just for an animation, or presentation. A good collision, gravity, etc. system is very much welcome, as are good GUI widgets.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the new [ForPlay](http://code.google.com/p/forplay/) from Google.

It compiles to java, javascript, android and more.

**Edit:** Moved and name changed to [PlayN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/)

There is also a stackoverflow [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playn)

Answer (score 0):

Potential ideas:

- [Processing](http://processing.org/) has been used to make some very good visualizations.... depending on what you want to do this may be a good option.
- [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) was designed as a framework for building Rich Internet Applications (a bit like Flash). I think it has a lot of the Flash-like features you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can take a look at [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/).